# A Tricky Question on Binomial::-

Tags: binomial-theorem

[image]

*I have got this question from my friend and, u know I have tried a lot on this question. I tried to take* $$\ o^2 + e^2 \ as 
\ (o+e)^2 - 2o\times e$$

I could find $o+e$, but I couldn't find $o\times e$.
*here the odd terms means the terms having position as* $$2z+1$$ from z=0...to n  and even terms having position as 2z from z=0 to n

Comment: $$ oe = {(xa)}^{n(n+1)\over2}\prod^{n}_{i = 0}{n \choose i} $$

Comment: How can you say that which term is even or which term is odd till you don't know anything about $x,a~and~n$

Comment: @HarshKumar First term is odd, second term is even and so on.

Comment: @A---B first term is odd or first term is on $odd^{th}$ place

Comment: @HarshKumar Yes I meant odd place.

Comment: @HarshKumar, it means odd place yeah

Comment: Then you should clarify your definition of even/odd in the question.

Comment: Hey @A---B  your formula is wrong check it out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The even part of a given function $f(x)$ is obtained as $f_e(x)=\frac12(f(x)+f(-x))$; the odd part can then be found as $f_o(x)=f(x)-f_e(x)=\frac12(f(x)-f(-x))$. The values of $o,e$ can then be deduced by evaluating these functions appropriately.